# Accessor issues in c++

Tags: c++

This is my code.When I'm trying to print the value from getter, it is giving me some special characters but not the value I actually set.

```
class Car{
    public:
    Car(char* manufacturer,char* modelName,int mfgYear,char* color,double cost,int mpg){
           strcpy(mfg,manufacturer);
           strcpy(this->color,color);
           strcpy(this->modelName,modelName);
           this->MfgYear=mfgYear;
           this->vehicleCost=cost;
           this->mpg=mpg;
            };
    char* getManufacturer();
    void setManufacturer(char* x);
    };

    char* Car::getManufacturer(){
                    return this->mfg;
                }

    void Car::setManufacturer(char* mfgName)
    {

       strcpy(this->mfg,mfgName);


    }

    int main(){
    Car().setManufacturer("asds");
    cout<<Car().getManufacturer();
    }
```

Comment: You aren't allocating memory for any of the places you call `strcpy` so you are likely overwriting other memory in your process when you do so.

Comment: @Mounica Show how are defined data members of the class?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `std::string`?

Comment: Use `std::string` and save yourself a lot of grief.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object of type Car on the stack, but you are not saving any reference to it. When you call Car().setManufacturer("asds"), it will create an object of type Car on the stack, but if you do not save a reference to it, you will technically lose it. What you want to do is assign it to something. Here is what you can do:

```
Car myCar;
myCar.setManufacturer("asds");
cout << myCar.getManufacturer();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code, currently:

**1. You're not initializing a Car object in your main method - there is no object to call these methods upon.  This can be fixed by modifying your main method:**

```
    int main() {
        Car c("Manufacturer", "Model", 2000, "Color", 9999.99, 20);
        c.setManufacturer("asds");
        cout << c.getManufacturer() << endl;
    }
```

**2. You are trying to copy data to objects that aren't initialized inside the class (MfgYear, vehicleCost, mpg, color, modelName, mfg).**

```
    private:
        int MfgYear;
        double vehicleCost;
        int mpg;
        char color[80];
        char modelName[80];
        char mfg[80];
```

I have included the corrected class below:

```
    class CarChar
    {
    private:
        int MfgYear;
        double vehicleCost;
        int mpg;
        char color[80];
        char modelName[80];
        char mfg[80];

    public:
        Car(char* manufacturer, char* modelName, int mfgYear, char* color, double cost, int mpg)
        {                
            // Copy the data to the objects
            strncpy(this->mfg, manufacturer, sizeof(this->mfg));
            strncpy(this->color, color, sizeof(this->color));
            strncpy(this->modelName, modelName, sizeof(this->modelName));
            this->MfgYear = mfgYear;
            this->vehicleCost = cost;
            this->mpg = mpg;
        }

        char* getManufacturer() {
            return this->mfg;
        }

        void setManufacturer(char* mfgName) {
            strncpy(this->mfg, mfgName, sizeof(this->mfg));
        }
    };
```

*Note: If you notice in the above class, I replaced all calls to strcpy to strncpy to reduce the chance of buffer overflow, a security problem.*